# What is the 的 doing in 他很快就会回来的?

Tags: translation

I came across this simple sentence:

He will be back soon.
他很快就会回来的。

I understand that the 就 is expressing earliness, but what is the 的 doing here? In the textbook 新的中国 it doesn't say 的 is part of the 就 construction, or on the allgrammar wiki here https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_earliness_with_%22jiu%22

Is 的 turning the 会回来 into a sort of adjective? Since 会 is an adverb I expected it to be followed only be the verb 回 with the directional complement 来 without the 的. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: search site for previous discussions of this question, grammar topic 是。。。的 sentences，是 or 的 can be omitted, omission of 是  happens generally with verb 会，

Comment: @user6065 Ah it seems it's this one then https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Uses_of_%22shi..._de%22#Indicating_a_tone_of_strong_affirmation_with_.E7.9A.84

I was only familiar with the past tense 是。。。的 thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native Chinese speaker, I seldom hear people say"他很快就会回来。" 
Because without the word "的" it sounds weird and unnatural.
There is no meaning of “的” in the sentence.
I think “的" use in the ending of this sentence is just make the sentence better.

Comment: 這要看說話的節奏快慢，平時會加“的”，但在趕時間的場合就會盡量縮短，這時候就不會加“的”。很多是用來調節語速和節奏感，達到節省力氣的目的，為的就是不要把某個字說得太長，把這個音節長的字替換成2個字，同時每個字的發音時間縮減為三分之二左右來減慢節奏。

Answer (score 1):

The "的" here is to express the speaker is sure about what he/she said.

So in this sentence, it's more like, "I'm sure he will come back soon."

In this usage, 会 or 不会 is often used.
For example, 他不常迟到，他一定会准时到的
(He's not often be late. (I'm sure) he will be on time.

For more examples, you can check the link below:
https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Using_%22de%22_(modal_particle)